Inserting image in test case fails with: Internal error: {'attachment_file': ['File contains forbidden tag: <xmp>']} with Kiwi TCMS 13.3
This is the log if a png is uploaded in the test case editor:
[-32603] Internal error: {'attachment_file': ['File contains forbidden tag: <xmp>']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/modernrpc/core.py", line 143, in execute
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/tcms/rpc/api/user.py", line 185, in add_attachment
    utils.add_attachment(
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/tcms/rpc/utils.py", line 103, in add_attachment
    raise ValueError(errors)
ValueError: {'attachment_file': ['File contains forbidden tag: <xmp>']}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/modernrpc/handlers/jsonhandler.py", line 182, in process_single_request
    result_data = _method.execute(context, args, kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/modernrpc/core.py", line 151, in execute
    raise RPCInternalError(str(exc)) from exc
modernrpc.exceptions.RPCInternalError: [-32603] Internal error: {'attachment_file': ['File contains forbidden tag: <xmp>']}
172.31.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2024:17:29:24 +0000] "POST /json-rpc/ HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "https://tcms.pe.loc/case/7/edit/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
[pid: 1170291|app: 0|req: 100959/200102] 172.31.0.1 () {62 vars in 1041 bytes} [Tue Sep  3 17:29:24 2024] POST /json-rpc/ => generated 152 bytes in 25 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 8 headers in 252 bytes (2 switches on core 0)

If a jpg is uploaded instead, the error changes to:
[-32603] Internal error: {'attachment_file': ['File contains forbidden tag: <rt>']}

